# Is there a way to sort data from different sheets and different places into one place? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'll try to explain the situation as best as possible.

So my issue is that I have is that there are five sheets with different information. There is a common column that I want to get, those are the "location", "date" and "time". With the date and time, one of the sheets (sheet sample three), has only the date. I want to collect the location, date and time and SORT them in order.

Sheet one

*might need to unmerge date and time into two different cells.

[image]

Sheet two

[image]

Sheet three

[image]

I want to display my sorted data like this. At first, I had a attempted to use `=SORT(arrayformula()datecolumn,true,timecolumn,true)`. But I had to put it on a different sheet.

[image: The result I want]

In Conclusion,

1. There are six seperate sheets including the final result above.
2. With the other five, four out of five are the same format to Sheet one and Sheet three being the only one with date.
3. Like I mention, the end result that I am try to aim for is above. However, the sheets do not have "the category" beside them, so I want to show that it came from one of the sheets. I do have a headings in the sheets if that makes it easy to use. I would like to display the category as much as possible.
4. Tried using `=countifs("range","date",true,"time",true)` but want to reduce the number of sheets to hide on this spreadsheet.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you expect from this question since you haven't supplied any sample data, but... as a guide I'd write a `QUERY` on the "Itinerary" sheet, stack the ranges from each sheet in the query range, and select the appropriate fields and sort them as required. If you want an example, I suggest that you edit your question to provide sample data (for each of the five sheets) as well an an example of the expected outcome.